# ReactJS - Objects Are Not Valid As React Child

Tags: reactjs

I want to add snippet of code into account-protected pages to ensure that if accessed without a valid token, the user is redirected to login page instead.

Hence, I have create a `VerifySignInStatus` function which takes in the component to be shown if authentification is successful as an argument, performs the verification, and if verification fails then displays the login page (i.e., `AuthPage` component), or if it succeeds then displays the desired component (passed as parameter to the function).

When verification fails, the code correctly renders `AuthPage`, however, when verification passes, the `<h1>` component is not displayed and instead an error is thrown into the console saying `Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {displayComponent}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`.

**VerifySignInStatus Function**

```
export function VerifySignInStatus(displayComponent) {
  const { token, removeToken, setToken } = UseToken(); // setToken, token, removeToken

  const [hasFetched, setHasFetched] = useState(false);
  const [isTokenValid, setIsTokenValid] = useState(false);

  const tokenExists = token && token !== "" && token !== undefined;
  if (tokenExists) {
    ValidateToken(token, setHasFetched, setIsTokenValid);
  }

  if (tokenExists && !hasFetched) {
    return <div>Loading</div>;
  }

  if (!tokenExists || !isTokenValid) {
    return <AuthPage setToken={setToken} />;
  }

  return displayComponent;
}
```

**Dashboard.js** (which I'm trying to access with a valid token)

```
import { VerifySignInStatus } from "./authentication/authFunctions";

function Dashboard() {
  return <VerifySignInStatus displayComponent={<h1>Dashboard</h1>} />;
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: should be `VerifySignInStatus({displayComponent})` with the `{}`

Comment: That solved it indeed, thanks! Sorry if it sounds like a silly question. I'm only few days into React and it's unlike anything I worked with before. Would you like to submit this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the complete props object as the variable `displayComponent`.

You want to extract it from the props like:

```
VerifySignInStatus({displayComponent}) {
....
}
```